# Use regex to remove everything but [a-zA-Z0-9-] from string

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, seo, preg-replace

I've search around on these forums, and it seems like everyone has a slight variation of my question.

I have the following string `To-Wage-a-64-Bit-Coup!` and I want to delete anything that's not a letter, number, or hyphen `[a-zA-Z0-9]` using `preg_replace()`. The end result would be that the exclamation mark would be removed.

I don't know all the characters which need to be removed, but I know what needs to stay. This is for generating a seo-friendly url. Not sure if a negative or a positive lookahead is what I need, or perhaps use something else like `preg_match()` to accomplish my ends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
preg_replace("([^a-zA-Z0-9-])","",$subject);
```

Put a `^` at the start of a `[...]` to negate its effect.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It's the simple things you forget. Was over thinking it too much.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = preg_replace("'[^A-Za-z0-9-]'", '', $string);
```

A-Za-z0-9- matches letters, numbers and the hyphen. The ^ at the start negates that character class, so instead it matches everything except those characters.

If this is for creating a URL friendly string you might also want to consider first converting spaces to hypens, removing multiple runs of hypens that may result from this, and converting the string to lower case.